# Filter from Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have a `Vue.js` web app that consumes data from an `express.js` API and shows the response array in a table. Each object of the array has unique id formed by `Name_Version` (for example  `P.90.001000-0004_2`). The problem is that I need to show only the last version of each one. For example, if the API response is:

```
[{id: P.90.001000-0004_1}, {id: P.90.001000-0004_2}, {id: P.90.001000-0004_3}, {id: P.90.002222-0025_1}, {id: P.90.002222-0025_2}]
```

the result array to show in the table would be:

```
[{id: P.90.001000-0004_3}, {id: P.90.002222-0025_2}]
```

It's been impossible for me to achieve this result, can anyone please help me?

Comment: That is a very bad format received from an API. I would migrate the grouping logic to the server rather than the client, otherwise you need to manually split the ids and get the latest one, which is somewhat expensive and senseless on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an object that maps the portion of the id without the version  to the entire object, and you can keep in this map only the latest version of each item:

```js
const data = [{id: 'P.90.001000-0004_1'}, {id: 'P.90.001000-0004_2'}, {id: 'P.90.001000-0004_3'}, {id: 'P.90.002222-0025_1'}, {id: 'P.90.002222-0025_2'}];
const map = {};

data.forEach((item) => {
  const [id, version] = item.id.split('_');
  const latestItem = map[id];
  
  if (!latestItem || latestItem.id.split('_')[1] < version) {
    map[id] = item;
  }
});

const filteredData = Object.values(map);
console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: You should ensure that `_` has only one occurrence, otherwise you should take the lastIndexOf of it.

Comment: Also, I guess you should also consider the case where no `_` exists in case there only is one instance and, for some reason, whoever made such API thought the `_` was not needed.

Comment: _ has only one occurrence in each object and all of them has that termination (from _0 to _X) so you can obviate this two things. Said that, this solution works perfectly. Thank you very very much!!

Comment: @titanlux619 Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to get the latest version, and then use `Object.entries` with `map` and `join` to put them back into format:

```js
const arr = [{id: 'P.90.001000-0004_1'}, {id: 'P.90.001000-0004_2'}, {id: 'P.90.001000-0004_3'}, {id: 'P.90.002222-0025_1'}, {id: 'P.90.002222-0025_2'}]


const latest = arr.reduce((a, {id}) => {
  const [k,v] = id.split('_')
  a[k] = +v > (a[k] || 0) ? v : a[k]
  return a
}, {})

const output = Object.entries(latest).map(pair => ({ id: pair.join('_')}))

console.log(output)
```

If you need to keep the rest of the properties, you can use a map, and keep reference to the original object by index:

```js
const arr = [{id: 'P.90.001000-0004_1'}, {id: 'P.90.001000-0004_2'}, {id: 'P.90.001000-0004_3'}, {id: 'P.90.002222-0025_1'}, {id: 'P.90.002222-0025_2'}]

const latest = arr.reduce((a, {id}, i) => {
  const [k,v] = id.split('_')
  if(!a.has(k) || +v > a.get(k)[0]) a.set(k, [+v, i])
  return a
}, new Map())

const output = [...latest.values()].map(([,i]) => arr[i])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This solution works, but the result array only contains de property id and  each object has 15 more properties that I need to show in the table.  how can I keep the rest of the properties of each object?

Comment: @titanlux619 Check my answer now 

Comment: This solution return the same number of objects that your previous solution and all properties of each object but there are a lot of duplicates. I tried to modify and improve it with no luck. @Alberto Trinidade Tavares's answer works like a charm anyways. Thank you very much to you too!